# Empty blocks and empty objects grammar conflict warnings

Tags: javascript, parsing, bison, shift-reduce-conflict, jison

I'm trying to implement a parser in [Jison](http://zaach.github.io/jison/). The parser has support for both JSON objects: `{ a: 1 }` and blocks: `if (true) { statement(); }`.

My grammar looks like:

```
block:
  : '{' '}'
  | '{' statementList '}'
  ;

objectExpression:
  : '{' '}'
  | '{' properties '}'
  ;
```

There's a `{}` rule in both `block` and `objectExpression` because I need to support both empty objects and empty blocks.

It works, but it outputs lots of warnings such as:

```
Conflict in grammar: multiple actions possible when lookahead token is ; in state 52
- reduce by rule: objectExpression -> { }
- reduce by rule: block -> { }
```

How can I fix or suppress these warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string `{}` could be parsed either as a block, or as an objectExpression. You have a few choices.

In Javascript parsers, if there is an ambiguity between `block` and `objectExpression`, it will choose the one that comes first in the parent rule. In the following expression, the empty block will be preferred over the empty object.

```
expression:
    : block
    | objectExpression
    ;
```

The parser will complain about any ambiguity (also known as shift/reduce conflict), but it will still work. Assuming the Jison parser is compatible with the Bison parser, use the [`expect` declaration](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Expect-Decl.html#Expect-Decl) to suppress the warning.

You could also make blocks and objectExpressions only appear in different contexts (e.g. blocks can only appear after `if` statements or `for` statements).  A third choice would be to remove support for empty objects.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up by adding another lex rule:

```
\{\} return 'EMPTY_OBJECT';
```

and changing the `objectExpression` to:

```
objectExpression:
  : 'EMPTY_OBJECT'
  | '{' properties '}'
  ;
```

It worked (even though it's a bit ugly).

Comment: I'm skeptical that this solution actually works (and not just because it confusingly makes `{}` and `{ }` syntactically distinct). Test it thoroughly. The correct solution will involve identifying the contexts in which the two empty braced syntax can occur.